# Axios and Express js upgrade to use http2

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, request, http2

I'm upgrading my express.js server to use http2 using spdy.

```
const server = spdy.createServer(app);
server.listen(8000, (err) => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('Listening on port', 8000);
});
```

All services are using Axios to make a request and `request` for proxying.

```
static fetchSomething = async (id) => {
  return await axios.get(`/api/my-service/getInfo?id=${id}`);
};
```

Also i'm using request as a proxy

```
router.post('`/api/my-service/getInfo', function(req,res){
  let url = `url`;
  let options = {
    url: url,
    headers: {...addHeader(req.headers)},
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
  };
  request.post(options).pipe(res);
});
```

So far what i've read that Axios and requesr doesnt really support http2. Shall i replace them with something else?

Thanks